# How to switch to personal team in Apple Developer Center

Tags: ios, code-signing-certificate

I am member of the enterprise development team in Apple Developer portal. I want to have my own application separately, but I can not found over all the apple developer site how to switch teams. Is it possible, or how should I develop my own applications ?